# Can the foundation for my garden shed be underground?

Tags: concrete, building-regulations, planning-permission

We are building a garden studio on a sloped ground. I am totally confused in regards to the concrete base.

To have an even base we didn't have to dig out ground at the back on the building but the front is 50cm into the ground. That is where our highest point from the ground of 2.5m will be.

The question is: can my base at the highest point be under ground or not?

Will my 2.5m roof be counted from the ground level or from my base level under ground?

Comment: A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your post to indicate where in the world you are as that will impact the answers you receive. Once you've done that (and while you're waiting for an answer or two), take the [tour] to learn how to get the most out of this site.

Comment: Of course a foundation can be in the ground. Almost every home built is so. What's the context around for your 2.5m measurement? Please revise to add detail.

Comment: Yes, the foundation can be underground.  But you would be wise to grade any adjacent surface to drain away from the shed.